# Chain repetitions of same generator in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator

Consider the following simple generator:

```
def simple_gen():
    for number in range(5):
        yield number ** 2
```

I'm willing to user `itertools.repeat` and `itertools.chain` to chain n times the generator to itself. For clarity consider the following (non-generator) example of the same:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
repetitions = itertools.repeat( array ,2)
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(repetitions)) -> [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

I want the same but using my own generator (simple_gen) instead of array. Of course a simple substitution does not work because `itertools.repeat` repeats the same object and therefore the following repetitions of the generator will be exhausted.

Some ideas of how to achieve this using the itertools module?

**I do not want to cast the generator to a list or another container.**

Comment: Do you know the length of the generator? If so, you could use `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: No, I do not know the length of the generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the generator output to a list first:

```
repeat(list(simple_gen()), 2)
```

You *can't* otherwise repeat a generator output. At most you could *recreate* the generator *count* number of times:

```
from itertools import repeat

def recreate(callable, count=None):
    for c in repeat(callable, count):
        yield from c()
```

in Python 3 and

```
from itertools import repeat

def recreate(callable, count=None):
    for c in repeat(callable, count):
        for val in c():
            yield val
```

for Python 2 and use that instead of `chain.from_iterable(repeat(callable(), count))`. Note that the generator function is **not called**, you pass in the function object itself instead.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> def simple_gen():
...     for number in range(5):
...         yield number ** 2
...
>>> def recreate(callable, count=None):
...     for c in repeat(callable, count):
...         for val in c():
...             yield val
...
>>> list(recreate(simple_gen, 2))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: I do not want to cast the generator to a list because it would fill my whole RAM. That's why i'm using generators. I will update my question with that.

Comment: @Dargor: which is why I gave you another option. There are no other choices, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, yes. It's not that i'ts a bad answer is that my question was incomplete and could lead to other answers using the casting to list. This is a great answer, sorry for the misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about a decorator:

```
from itertools import repeat

class repeat_gen:
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, gen):
        for it in repeat(gen, self.count):
            yield from it()

@repeat_gen(3)
def simple_gen():
    for number in range(5):
        yield number ** 2

print(list(simple_gen))
```

Note that the following without `itertools.repeat` works too. As `simple_gen` is passed as a generic function to the decorator, it can be called several times.

```
class repeat_gen:
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen
        def repeat_gen():
            for i in range(self.count):
                yield from self.gen()
        return repeat_gen

@repeat_gen(3)
def simple_gen():
    for number in range(5):
        yield number ** 2

print(list(simple_gen()))
```

Comment: This code uses an odd mix of Python 2.X and Python 3.X idioms. For example, you don't need to inherit from `object` and you can `yield from it()` instead of looping over it. If you want to make the code work with both versions, you can add the arguments to the `super` call. I like the idea of the decorator though.

Comment: I never came accross `yield from it()`. Thanks ! I like it a lot. I am in transition to Python3, maybe that's why the code looks odd. What are the Python2 features appart not using from `yield from it()` ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`, i.e. `class repeat_gen:` would be a more common declaration.

Comment: Sure, I changed this in the answer.